# How to replace values of a dictionary in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Shouldn't this be creating a new dictionary and be able to replace its values everytime I call the getVal function?

```
var dict = [];

    function getVal(inarr, element, data) {
        var arr = inarr[element].map((item) => item[data]);
        return arr;
    };

    console.log(getVal(event, 'foo', 'bar'));
```

Comment: From what I gather, `event` is a dictionary of dictionary arrays. `getVal` simply returns an array at this point, and the `dict.push` instruction is not even reached. What are you trying to do?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `dict.push(element[arr])` ? From you invocation, this line will be translated as `dict.push('muons[arr]')` which makes no sense. Also, you are **returning** before the statement, therefore, this will not be executed

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right now you pointing out. Although, I would like to get the values of the function and make a dictionary. The desired result I would like to make is muons = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3] where values are result of the var arr = inarr[element].map((item) => item[data]); Hope that makes sense. Muons contains other arrays within so with this I will be able to pick what I want and make a new array.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. You don't need `dict` at all then. `arr` should be `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]`, unless the data in `json` is in a different format from what `getVal` expects. What does your `json` look like ?

Comment: Having expected output in the comments and not having input at all does not make for a good question.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getVal(inarr, element, data) {
    var arr = inarr[element].map((item) => item[data]);
    return arr;
};

console.log(getVal(event, 'foo', 'bar'));
```

Comment: try adding some detail to your answer and pointing out the error/mistake in the OP rather than just pasting the code here

Answer (score 0):

It's guess work at best because your question isn't clear and input is missing but you could try something like this:

```js
    //keys is an array of string or function
    // if it's a function then it will pass current object
    // to that function
    function getMember(object,keys){
      return keys.reduce(
        function(acc,key){
          if(acc===undefined){
            return acc;
          }
          if(typeof key === "function"){
            return key(acc);
          }
          return acc[key];
        }
        ,object
      )
    }

    function getVal(object) {
      return getMember(
        object,
        [
          "foo", // get member foo is an array of {bar:number}
          function(x){ //map array of {bar:number} to array of number
            return x.map(
              function(x){
                return x.bar; 
              });
          }
        ]
      );
    };
    var event = {
      foo:[
        {
          bar:1
        },
        {
          bar:2
        }
      ]
    };
    console.log(getVal(event));// should log [1,2]
```